# Need Digistump library for QWERTY keyboard and Fixes for my issues!

Tags: avr, attiny85, digispark, arduino-ide-2

Hello there I am trying to install `Digistump` library to support ATTiny85 by digispark. But I am encountering a problem when trying to install Digistump AVR boards after adding an additional board URL preference as the library doesn't shows up after searching.I dont know what's the problem even after I tried from the fixes from other solutions across the web.
[image]

So, I made an alternative method to work the board by installing `ATTinyCore` library. But it doesn't support `DIGIKEYBOARD` actions. So when I try to download from library manager there is only packages for AZERTY & Belgian AZERTY layout.
[image] [image]

So for me I need a package that support QWERTY layout. How to install the library.?

Answer (score 1):

The description of DigiKeyboardFr says it is “based on
[DigisparkKeyboard](https://github.com/digistump/DigisparkArduinoIntegration/tree/master/libraries/DigisparkKeyboard) library”, and gives the link to that library.
DigisparkKeyboard doesn't seem to be available from the Arduino library
manager: you will most likely have to install it manually. Manual
installation of Arduino libraries is widely documented.

Comment: May I know how to install it manually?? for the specified keyboard layout..